# Have administrators approve user accounts after users confirm their e-mail addresses and set passwords

Tags: users

For my current Drupal 7 project I set up the account creation process the following way:

1. User can register for an account.
2. User will receive an email telling him that the account needs to approved by the administrator
3. Email is being sent to the administrator asking him to approve the account.
4. Once the administrator has approved the account another email is sent to the user with a link, leading the user back to the portal to set his new password and to log in.

What I am after is a slight change to this process:

I want the user to get the email first to set his password and therefore confirm his email address.

Once that is done I want the email being sent to the administrator to approve the account.

Is that possible?

Thanks, Uwe

Comment: How about leaving the process as is but allow the admin to approve the users by giving them a new "Approved User" role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is kinda like what frazras said, leave the regular auth process but use rules to send an email to admin group/role when a user confirms registration.

You'll probably want to use views to create a view then that looks for the user role (the default confirmed user) and create a confirmed or approved user role (be sure to strip the user role of all permissions & grant permissions to your new role that are how you want them). In the view you are creating make sure to exclude anyone that's a member of any role other than just user & maybe anon.

The link to that view in an email to admins makes it easy to monitor You could probably put in a link to approve via the email though I'd strongly advise not letting users approve users without verification unless you're comfortable with your ability to secure it.

http://drupal.org/project/Rules
http://drupal.org/project/views